# Drupal 6 Views - Get & Set remembered filter values

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a view with filters, with "remember last option".
I need to get the remembered values from these filters, in order to apply these filters to other sub-views on the site. 
Also I need not only to get these values, I need to set these values to another value, o reset them.
Please give a clue, I don't know where to begin. Views code is to big :(
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some research in the database & printing the $_SESSION superglobal I found that these values are in $_SESSION['views']. So, I can read these values & also can update them. Problem solved :)